# What is the domain in a tikz parametric plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, domain

I don't understand what's going on here. If the domain of the parametric parameter `\t` is 0:100, then the function sin(2pi*t) should oscillate about 100 times, but it only oscillates a couple. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[x=.6\textwidth,y=.6\textwidth]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray, step=.1] (0.0,0.0) grid (1,1);
    \draw [ thick,  domain=0:100, samples=40, smooth, variable=\t] 
    plot ({\t/100}, {sin(2*pi*\t)*.5+.5});
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the `domain` right. The problem is that the trigonometric functions in TikZ are (oddly, in my opinion) in degrees by default. So `2*pi*\t` with `\t` between `0` and `100` will give you the sine function (in degrees) between `0` and `628.3` degrees (which is about `10.96` radians) which almost `1.75` periods of the function. This is exactly what you see there: one full period and `3/4` of another.

You can tell Ti*k*Z to use radians by appending an `r` to the argument or using the `rad` function (see page 1005 of the Ti*k*Z-PGF manual, section 93.3.4 “Trigonometric functions”). I also added the FPU to allow the domain up to 100 and increased the number of samples to 400 following Kpym's suggestion (notice the aliasing):

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[x=.6\textwidth,y=.6\textwidth]
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \draw[very thin,color=gray, step=.1] (0.0,0.0) grid (1,1);
    \draw [ thick,  domain=0:100, samples=400, smooth, variable=\t]
    plot ({\t/100}, {sin(2*pi*\t r)*.5+.5});
  \end{scope}%                   ^
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with `samples=400,smooth` it looks better, but this is not the question ;)

Comment: @Kpym Certainly! I just removed the `smooth` to show that 100 cycles with 40 samples won't do (unless OP wants to show the aliasing). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Doh! Degrees... Yeah, don't know why that didn't occur to me. I'm just so used to thinking in radians. Usually trigonometric functions are defined assuming radians, but I guess it makes sense since everywhere else in latex assumes angles are degrees. I actually did try and turn up the samples at first  - thought it was just aliasing.

Comment: @argentum2f Yes, as I said “oddly”. All programming languages I know (which aren't _that_ many, but...) have a `sin` function for argument radians and `sind` function for argument in degrees. Anyhow, Till must have had his reasons :)